# Cross correlation issue in python

Tags: python, time-series, synchronization, cross-correlation

I'm trying to synchronize two signals that have the same shape. One signal is shorter than the other. To do so I use cross correlation which seems to work but not giving the right result. The best lag given is around 269000 but the real best lag to have the signals perfectly aligned is around 129000. I don't know why cross correlation isn't working properly ...

Here is my code :

```
def sync_signals(self):
        accel_path = self.accel_path_text.text()

        samrate, data = wavfile.read(str(accel_path))
        accelData = pd.DataFrame(data)

        rafale_path = self.rafale_path_text.text()
        rafaleData = pd.read_csv(rafale_path, delimiter=';', header="infer")

        stat_path = self.stat_path_text.text()
        df = pd.read_csv(stat_path)

        start_time = df.iloc[1][2]
        end_time = df.iloc[1][3]
        measurement_time = int(end_time)-int(start_time)

        temps_entre_points_accel = measurement_time/(len(accelData))
        accelData.insert(0, 'Heure', accelData.index * temps_entre_points_accel)
        
        def str_to_milliseconds(time_str):
            # Séparer les composants de la chaîne de temps
            hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds = map(int, time_str.split(':'))

            # Calculer le total des millisecondes
            total_milliseconds = (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000 + milliseconds

            return total_milliseconds
        
        rafaleData.insert(0, 'Temps', [str_to_milliseconds(time_str) for time_str in rafaleData.iloc[:, 0]])

        # Get the two signals as numpy arrays
        accel_signal = accelData.values[:, 1]
        accel_time = accelData.values[:, 0]
        rafale_signal = rafaleData['GAMMAZ (g)'].values
        rafale_time = rafaleData['Temps'].values

        # Determine which signal is shorter
        if len(accel_signal) < len(rafale_signal):
            short_signal = accel_signal
            short_time = accel_time
            long_signal = rafale_signal
            long_time = rafale_time
        else:
            short_signal = rafale_signal
            short_time = rafale_time
            long_signal = accel_signal
            long_time = accel_time

        long_time_simulated = np.arange(short_time[0],short_time[len(short_time)-1],20)
        
        interpolation_function = interp1d(short_time, short_signal, kind='linear')
        resampled_signal = interpolation_function(long_time_simulated)

        print(pd.DataFrame(long_time))
        print(pd.DataFrame(long_time_simulated))

        



        shifted_versions = [
            (pd.DataFrame(long_signal*0.00390625), pd.DataFrame(resampled_signal))
        ]

        print(shifted_versions)
        def shift_for_maximum_correlation(x, y):
            correlation = correlate(x, y, mode="full")
            lags = correlation_lags(x.size, y.size, mode="full")
            lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
            print(f"Best lag: {lag}")
            if lag < 0:
                y = y.iloc[abs(lag):].reset_index(drop=True)
            else:
                x = x.iloc[lag:].reset_index(drop=True)
            return x, y
        
        def plot_correlation(x, y, text):
            # plot 
            plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
            plt.plot(x)
            plt.plot(y)
            plt.legend(loc="best")
            plt.show()

        for x, y in shifted_versions:
            shifted_x, shifted_y = shift_for_maximum_correlation(x, y)
            plot_correlation(shifted_x, shifted_y, text="after shifting")
```

This is long_time :
0             0.0
1            20.0
2            40.0
3            60.0
4            80.0
...           ...
475245  9504900.0
475246  9504920.0
475247  9504940.0
475248  9504960.0
475249  9504980.0

This is long_time_simulated (Initially measure points were randomly took so I resampled short_time)
0      1742887
1      1742907
2      1742927
3      1742947
4      1742967
...        ...
86236  3467607
86237  3467627
86238  3467647
86239  3467667
86240  3467687

This is long_signal :
0       0.382812
1       0.371094
2       0.425781
3       0.410156
4       0.503906
...          ...
475245 -0.074219
475246 -0.078125
475247 -0.062500
475248 -0.046875
475249 -0.046875

This is resampled_signal :
0      0.935748
1      0.935736
2      0.935724
3      0.935712
4      0.935700
...         ...
86236  0.164273
86237  0.143966
86238  0.123658
86239  0.103350
86240  0.083042

This is the [result graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9xyh.png) that i obtain instead of this [well synchronized signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnxOs.png)

You'll see here the [two signals not synchronized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHtqm.png)

Thanks for your help !

I tried to filter the long_signal which has some noise but it didn't change anything. I also tried the other modes of the cross correlation but it also didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you shift the baseline of the short signal, so that it is closer to the baseline of the long signal? Maybe it is matching the wrong region because the amplitudes there are larger, therefore closer to the short signal.

Comment: I'll try to do that and I'll keep you updated

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work ...

Comment: Can you share the series somewhere?